# How to localize system buttons into the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, localization

My app uses custom localization for interactive language changing. The solution can be found [here](https://github.com/maximbilan/ios_language_manager). 
The problem is that the default view controllers (like `AVPlayerViewController`, `SFSafariViewController` etc.) localize the buttons ('Done', 'Cancel' etc.) based on the **device language**. 
I tried adding to localization files the custom localization for *'Done'* string but it doesn't work.

[image: SFSafariViewController]

I do not want to have my app localized in German and SFSafariViewController localized in English (device language).

If you have met the problem like this one please give me your solution. 
Thanks

Comment: I think that they will changed if only the user changed the OS language.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Actually I don't want to force a user to change the iOS language. Therefore, I'm looking for a solution programmatically.